# Does this series $2 + 4 + \cdots + \sqrt{\sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n} + n$ have a general term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Does this sum simplify to a general term in terms of $n$? If so, how would you arrive at that term?

$2  + 4 + \cdots + \sqrt{\sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n} + n$.

Thanks.

Comment: Always?  Assuming $n$ is finite so that the series is a finite series?

Comment: I don't think it's really clear (at least to me) what you're asking. Could you elaborate q2liu?

Comment: What do you mean by "converge to"?  Convergence is an issue with *infinite* series.  If that's what you intend, then this certainly diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Very true. My question was not formulated correctly, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: The first 3 terms don't agree with your last 3 for any value of n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed by Semsem, there is an inconsistency between the first three terms and the general term.

Let us assume that you have $$a_i= \sqrt[4]{i}+\sqrt{i}+i$$ and that you ask for the summation of the $a_i$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n$, there is a formula for $$\sum _{i=1}^n a_i=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)+H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$ If the summation starts at $i=2$ (as it seems in the post), then $$\sum _{i=2}^n a_i=\frac{1}{2} (n-2) (n+3)+H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$ where appear the harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the general terms you can see that each number is the square of its previous.
Is this what you're looking for?
$$f(k)=2^{2^k}$$

This one assumes that your first number is incorrect. So your sequence is: $2, 4, 16, 256...$

Comment: This should be a comment (in my opinion), in that it is asking OP for clarification, rather than answering the question, which here was for a formula for the sum.

Comment: maybe it should be. however it's not the answer. it's a hint. it's stating the closed form and op may be able to proceed from here.

Comment: ^This is indeed the equation used to derive each term of the sum I posed.